# flutter horizontal listview

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I'm trying to make this list horizontally with 4 columns in Flutter, but after a whole day I can't adapt it to the screen on mobile, sometimes it gets compressed or sometimes it disappears, please help me with my code.

```
Widget favorites() {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
    child: HeaderDashboard(
      title: 'Favorites',
      onPressedSeeAll: () {},
      showSeeAllButton: true,
      child: Observer(
        builder: (_) {
          final categories = favoriteStore.favoriteList;
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: categories.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    side: BorderSide(width: 2),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(categories[index].photo),
                    backgroundColor: const Color(0xff6ae792),
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    categories[index].title,
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text('Item description'),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```